# Получить почту юзера через api Vkontate

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, email

Вопрос лишь в том, можно ли получить почту пользователя через api Контакта?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет. В рамках безопасности аккаунтов пользователей нельзя

UPD. На сегодня получить почту пользователя стало возможным: https://vk.com/dev/permissions

Comment: Small Update :)

Answer (score 2):

Смешно, что Oauth разрешает использовать почту.
И facebook и твиттер спокойно отдают почту юзера.
Тут важно пароль хранить и он хранится. А контакт нет...